# Work + heat absorbed in a thermodynamic process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work

The question describes a simple isobaric closed cycle. The temperature is on the y-axis and volume on the other. There are 4 states. The question asks: ''Find the work done on the gas in the cycle and the heat absorbed by the gas in the cycle''.

My question is 2-fold:

1) the work done would be equal to the negative of the heat absorbed, correct?

2) I don't understand at which points of the cycle heat is either absorbed or lost and how to determine that.

Comment: Where is the figure?

Comment: Use $$ ∆H = nC_{p} ∆T$$
When T increase energy is gained and when Temp reduce energy is released.

Comment: @ChesterMiller there isn't much to this figure. It's a process with 4 states (a rectangle). And it starts on the bottom left corner at the lowest temp and lowest volume.

Comment: Do they give you actual temperature and volume values, or do they just label temperatures and volumes with subscripts?  Either way, what are they?

Comment: There are no values at all, only variables with subscripts such as $T_1$ and $V_1$